# Sql query to get the most popular post in rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I have this sql query that I'm using to get the most popular posts based on votes and each of these posts has a link to them..

I want to get the posts that have unique links and only the ones with the highest votes.

```
ListsPost.find_by_sql("SELECT distinct lists_posts.*,
          COALESCE(rs_reputations.value, 0) AS votes FROM \"lists_posts\" LEFT JOIN rs_reputations ON
          lists_posts.id = rs_reputations.target_id AND rs_reputations.target_type = 'ListsPost' AND
          rs_reputations.reputation_name = 'votes' AND rs_reputations.active = 't'  ORDER BY votes desc, lists_posts.updated_at desc")
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any more detailed infomrations, I build this query, so hope for the best

```
SELECT lists_posts.*, rs_reputations.value
  FROM \"lists_posts\" 
  LEFT JOIN rs_reputations 
    ON  lists_posts.id = rs_reputations.target_id 
   AND rs_reputations.target_type = 'ListsPost' 
   AND rs_reputations.reputation_name = 'votes' 
   AND rs_reputations.active = 't'  
   AND rs_reputations.value IN (     SELECT MAX(COALESCE(rs_reputations.value, 0)) AS max_votes 
                          FROM \"lists_posts\" 
                          LEFT JOIN rs_reputations 
                            ON  lists_posts.id = rs_reputations.target_id 
                           AND rs_reputations.target_type = 'ListsPost' 
                           AND rs_reputations.reputation_name = 'votes' 
                           AND rs_reputations.active = 't'  
                         )
```

Two steps:

1) The sub-select found one maximum value `MAX(COALESCE(rs_reputations.value, 0))`
2) The main-select search and show for all record with this rs_reputations.value

With detailed information about the table structure, my query could be optimized.

Comment: That almost seems to work. The thing is, Each lists_posts has a post inside it which I want to be find the lists_posts with the same posts but only return the one with the highest vote

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, I decided to start from the beginning and I came up with this. It seems to work but could do with a little refining.

```
SELECT lp.*, COALESCE(rs_reputations.value, 0) as votes
FROM lists_posts AS lp
INNER JOIN(
  SELECT lists_posts.post_id, lists_posts.id, MAX(rs_reputations.value)
  FROM lists_posts
  LEFT JOIN rs_reputations
  ON lists_posts.id = rs_reputations.target_id
  GROUP BY lists_posts.post_id)l
ON lp.post_id = l.post_id
AND lp.id = l.id
LEFT JOIN rs_reputations ON
  lp.id = rs_reputations.target_id
AND rs_reputations.target_type = 'ListsPost'
AND rs_reputations.reputation_name = 'votes'
AND rs_reputations.active = 't'
ORDER BY votes desc, updated_at desc
```